# Swagger express framework with socket on AWS server is not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, socket.io, swagger

My server code is this -

```
var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
        io.on('connection', function (client) {
            client.on('error', function (err) {
        });
    });
server.listen(3000);
    // some code
SwaggerExpress.create(config, function (err, swaggerExpress) {
    // enable SwaggerUI
    app.use(SwaggerUi(swaggerExpress.runner.swagger));

     // install middleware
     swaggerExpress.register(app);
     app.listen(8080);
});
```

Client side code -

```
var socket = io( 'https://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.on('chargebee_event', function (data) {
    });
});
```

This code is working on local but it is not working on AWS server. I have enabled 3000 port with inbound rule **custom TCP** source is Custome with 0.0.0.0/0